# Bash in Python: Delete single quote

Tags: python, bash

I'm executing a shell command in python but when it comes to execute this one in python (which deletes from a text file this symbol '  sigle quote) it doesn't work at all. Please could yout help me with it.

Command:

```
commands.getoutput('tr -d "'" < /tmp/file_1.txt > /tmp/file_2.txt')
```

P.S.
The shell command executed in a terminal does work.

Thanks

Comment: Please read http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A syntax highlighter should already show you the problem. You need to escape the single quote inside the command string:

```
commands.getoutput('tr -d "\'" < /tmp/file_1.txt > /tmp/file_2.txt')
```

Comment: Even easier, use one of the triple-quoted strings: `'''tr -d "'" < /tmp/file_1.txt > /tmp/file_2.txt'''`.